Nested subtree traversal in the insert algorithm DOM
In general, those who worked with DOM, heard about insertion methods, for example, append, prepend and some others.
I decided to study how the whatwg specification describes them and I encountered difficulties.
This is what I am talking about (insert algorithm):


For each node in nodes, in tree order:

Adopt node into parent’s node document.
If child is null, then append node to parent’s children.
Otherwise, insert node into parent’s children before child’s index.
If parent is a shadow host whose shadow root’s slot assignment is "named" and node is a slottable, then assign a slot for node.
If parent’s root is a shadow root, and parent is a slot whose assigned nodes is the empty list, then run signal a slot change for
parent.
Run assign slottables for a tree with node’s root.
For each shadow-including inclusive descendant inclusiveDescendant of node, in shadow-including tree order:

Run the insertion steps with inclusiveDescendant.
If inclusiveDescendant is connected, then:

If inclusiveDescendant is custom, then enqueue a custom element callback reaction with inclusiveDescendant, callback name
"connectedCallback", and an empty argument list.
Otherwise, try to upgrade inclusiveDescendant.








That is, the algorithm indicates that we have a cycle in step 7 in which it goes through the nodes of a light tree recursively (DFS) and performs some steps for each node.
But we also have a substep 7.7, which is a subcycle and which, logically, is even broader since it looks at not only light nodes, but also looks at shadow nodes and their descendants.
Now let's imagine such an example, we have some document there is a body node in which it is empty and we want to insert complex markup (of course it will be node with descendants) into it via the append method, let's say it will be like this:
<section>
  <div id="1">
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <component-description>
      #shadow-root
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    </component-description>
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    <title>Title 2</title>
    <component-description>
      #shadow-root
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    </component-description>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    <title>Title 3</title>
    <component-description>
      #shadow-root
        <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    </component-description></div>
</section>

So when the insertion algorithm is run, when we enter the tree traversal cycle step 7, do some steps for the section node (specified above), then meet step 7.7 and traverse all nodes that contain section and its children including shadow ones. Is it?
Okay, now when we return to step 7, we get a new node that is a child of section, this is div with id="1". Now some steps will be performed for it, and then step 7.7, which will again traverse all nodes for div.
If we analyze the traversal by nodes, then div with id="1" and some of its children will be traversed by step 7.7 several times. For what?
Main question: Why use For each node in nodes, in tree order when the clause For each shadow-including inclusive descendant inclusiveDescendant of node, in shadow-including tree order is much broader and traverse shadow nodes?
I understand the difference between the traversal cycles (one includes traversal of shadow trees, the other does not). Probably I am missing something. I need help.

There is an even stranger part of this same algorithm below.


For each node of nodes, in tree order:

For each shadow-including inclusive descendant inclusiveDescendant of node, in shadow-including tree order, append inclusiveDescendant to staticNodeList.




Why is this done? I'm probably missing something.

I wrote a little example that demonstrates that some nodes will be visited a several times:


let wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.setHTMLUnsafe(`<section>
  <div id="1">
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <component-description>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </template>
    </component-description>
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    <title>Title 2</title>
    <component-description>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </template>
    </component-description>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    <title>Title 3</title>
    <component-description>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </template>
    </component-description></div>
</section>`)
let targetNode = wrapper.firstElementChild;

/// This is step 7 in spec
function traverseTree(node, shadows){
  if (node.visited === undefined) node.visited = 0;
  ++node.visited;
  node.setAttribute?.("visited", node.visited);
  console.log(node, "=>", node.visited);

  if (typeof shadows === "function") shadows(node);

  for (let child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling){
      traverseTree(child, shadows);
  }
}

function traverseTreeWithShadows(node){
  if (node.visited === undefined) node.visited = 0;
  ++node.visited
  node.setAttribute?.("visited", node.visited);

  if (node.shadowRoot) traverseTreeWithShadows(node.shadowRoot);
  for (let child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
      traverseTreeWithShadows(child);
  }
}

traverseTree(targetNode, traverseTreeWithShadows)




If I understand correctly, your question (the sentence that ends with a question mark) is literally just "Is it?" or perhaps it is "For what?".  Without context, those sentences don't stand on their own. Consider making your critical question sentence(s) self-contained.  And consider asking only one question.  The earlier in your post you can get to it, the better as well.

@wyck The question is clear if you read the whole text of the question, but okay, I added an obvious sentence that clearly speaks about the problem of the question.

Two things you got confused about here:
In your scenario nodes is actually just « node », i.e. a list with a single item node (the <section> element). The case where nodes size is greater than one is when node was a DocumentFragment.


Let nodes be node’s children, if node is a DocumentFragment node; otherwise « node ».


So the outer loop actually loops only once.
Then, it seems you thought the insertion steps would somehow reenter this algorithm? It won't. The insertion steps are different algorithms entirely. It's basically callbacks that are to be ran for some elements (like loading an <iframe>'s content, for instance).
So until step 7, only the <section> element has been visited by the outer loop, and the insertion steps of each of its descendants have been called.
Then the step 11 does loop once more over the descendants in order to get a static list of descendant nodes. To paraphrase the note just above, it's done in order to avoid having a live list when firing the post-connection-steps because these steps can execute code which could modify the tree and thus affect the live list. Having a static one, we're sure every descendant gets its post-connection-steps fired only once.

It's confusing that step 7 adds in tree order to the usual For each node in nodes, if this addition were not there I would understand it as enumeration of nodes. But if you understand it as an enumeration of the transferred nodes, then all misunderstanding is reduced to nothing. I don't quite understand why the addition in tree order is used here, it's really confusing.

@MaximPro the tree order here acts on the list of nodes nodes, which is either a single item list « node », as in your example with the <section>, or the children of a DocumentFragment. Note that its children do not encompass all its descendants (unlike what we have in 7.7), it's really just the nodes that have the DocumentFragment as direct parent. It doesn't ask to pick more nodes, it just uses this order to sort the list. It's probably a bit redundant in this case since children is already an ordered set, but there might be cases where it could be different? Not quite sure.

You are saying it the way I once perceived this algorithm. In any case, this logic sounds more reasonable than the way I presented it in the question.


the algorithm indicates that we have a cycle in step 7 in which it goes through the nodes of a light tree recursively (DFS) and performs some steps for each node.

When the spec says


For each node in nodes, in tree order:


that’s like a for (let node of nodes) loop, to use JavaScript syntax. node is a name and nodes is a set of nodes defined in step 1:


Let nodes be node’s children, if node is a DocumentFragment node; otherwise « node ».


It’s not a recursive tree traversal, the loop is just done over the set in tree order (which doesn’t even matter when you’re not inserting a DocumentFragment – any other node just runs the loop once with node).
Here’s a modification of the snippet with the corresponding misinterpretation fixed:


let wrapper = document.createElement("div");
wrapper.setHTMLUnsafe(`<section>
  <div id="1">
    <title>Title 1</title>
    <component-description>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </template>
    </component-description>
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    <title>Title 2</title>
    <component-description>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </template>
    </component-description>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    <title>Title 3</title>
    <component-description>
        <template shadowrootmode="open">
            <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
        </template>
    </component-description></div>
</section>`)
let targetNode = wrapper.firstElementChild;

/// This is step 7 in spec
function applyToNodes(node, shadows) {
  let nodes =
    node.nodeType === Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE
      ? node.childNodes
      : [node];

  for (let node_ of nodes) {
    traverseTreeWithShadows(node_);
  }
}

function traverseTreeWithShadows(node) {
  if (node.visited === undefined) node.visited = 0;
  ++node.visited;
  node.setAttribute?.("visited", node.visited);

  if (node.shadowRoot) traverseTreeWithShadows(node.shadowRoot);
  for (let child = node.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
    traverseTreeWithShadows(child);
  }
}

applyToNodes(targetNode, traverseTreeWithShadows);
console.log(targetNode.outerHTML);




If you read the specification, you would know that "in tree order" means traversing the tree using DFS, which is a recursive traversal.

Even if it's not a recursive traversal (which doesn't change the essence), then it looks like for (let node of nodes) { for (let node2 of nodesWithShadows)}, which still traverses n*k times.

@MaximPro: Ooh, snarky and wrong. “In tree order“ is the same order as a (suitably ordered…) DFS, not the same nodes. The loop looks like for (let node of nodes) { for (let inclusiveDescendant of nodeAndDescendants(node)) … }, which makes perfect sense.

Even if we take your design (which is what I had in mind), we will still visit some nodes multiple times. Which looks unoptimized. And what's the point of using a tree traversal while embedding a tree traversal that includes shadow descendants? Wouldn't it be simpler to just make a single traversal that includes shadow descendants?

@MaximPro: No nodes are visited multiple times (since nodes consists of disjoint trees), and there is no embedded tree traversal (since looping over nodes is not a tree traversal). Also, again: nodes is usually one element. The only time the outer step 7 runs more than one iteration is when you pass a DocumentFragment with multiple nodes immediately inside it.

Done, formally the example corresponds to the fact that a cycle in a cycle occurs. Some nodes are visited many times. Check the code in my question.

@MaximPro: Your step 7 is wrong, because it’s recursive. See edit.

Funny, yes in that case everything works correctly. But then why does step 7 have the addition in tree order? It looks like it needs to traverse the DOM tree, from the passed node.

@MaximPro: It’s good to be explicit about the order of iteration, and tree order is a very common order across all DOM operations, so it’s conveniently there. It specifies a behavior, not an implementation (traversing the whole tree to sort nodes before looping over it would be a correct implementation, but a badly optimized one).
